# inline margins on pagination

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a pagination navigation element from a list of links. The page numbers should be center aligned and the prev/next buttons float to the left and right edge of the parent element respectively.

However I can't quite get the elements to behave right.

When I set the list elements to `display:inline` the page numbers don't align due to vertical margins not being calculated on inline elements:
[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/PftgP/

And when using `display:inline-block` instead, the page number margins work, but the prev/next buttons no longer float
[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/LDzgK/1/

Without resorting to crazy position:relative hacks or changing the html, is there an easy way I can get both the page numbers to stay vertically aligned, and the prev/next buttons to float correctly? I'm sure I'm missing an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:inline-block` in to the anchor in your first fiddle file

[jfFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/PftgP/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I knew it was a simple fix :)